# Need to ship logs to elastic from EKS

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluentd, amazon-eks

We have an EKS cluster running and we are looking for best practices to ship application logs from pods to Elastic.
In the EKS workshop there is an option to ship the logs to cloudwatch and then to Elastic.

Wondered if there is an option to ship the logs directly to Elastic, or to understand best practices.

Additional requirement: 
We need the logs to determine from which namespace the logs is coming from and to deliver a dedicated index

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy EFK stack in kubernetes cluster. Follow the reference --> https://github.com/acehko/kubernetes-examples/tree/master/efk/production

Fluentd would be deployed as DaemonSet so that one replica is run on each node collecting the logs from all pods and push them to elasticsearch

Comment: what about the logs per namespace. a fluentd is running in node level which mean it collects all pods logs on that node. How can I distinguish logs of specific pods which run on separate ns

Comment: with fluentd you can collect pod labels, namespace etc. you can define dashboards in kibana to look at the pods at namespace level

Comment: can you share a reference how can I provide privileges to the fluentd to collect pods metadata alongside with the logs .. ? or is it like that by default

Comment: https://www.katacoda.com/javajon/courses/kubernetes-observability/efk